# Best internatonalization library for Vue with modular architecture

Tags: javascript, vue.js, internationalization

My Vue.js project is divided into independent 'apps', e.g. *news*, *events*, *contacts* etc. As each such app is self-contained (which is also reflected in the directory layout), I do not want to have a centralized locale folder / file but rather have each app have its own locale file.

What internationalization libraries for Vue can you recommend that support such modularity?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what an 'independent app' means exactly for you, but in case each app has a separate Vue instance, you can use whichever internalization library you like and attach each instance its own internalization instance without a problem. For each of these internalization instances you can its own locale file. I personally prefer [vue-i18n](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/).